# Mongoid validation validates_inclusion_of is not giving me an error

Tags: mongoid

I have a mongodb document, and I am trying to create a validation

```
class Calculator
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :a, type: String
  field :b, type: String
  field :operator, type: String

  validates_inclusion_of :operator, in: %w[sum difference multiplication division]
```

Then when I create a document in the console with an invalid operator field it doesn't give me an error.

```
c = Calculator.new(a: 3, b: 4, operator: 'fdad')
```

Comment: If you try `c.valid?`, it should return false. When you create a new element using `Model.new` the document lives in the memory. The validation starts when you try to call the `valid?` method. You can also get a list of validation errors using `c.errors` after calling `c.valid?`.

Answer (score 1):

Validations are performed on persistence, e.g. when you call `save` or `save!`. They are not performed when you instantiate models (`new` call).